# Creating a graph in ASP.NET with Morris.js with AJAX and http handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, httphandler, morris.js

Hi am trying to learn how to create a line graph in asp.net using morris.js plugin. I am only able to display one label and one value from the table but I am able to display the values in the graph when i use the label  as DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToString("yyy-MM-dd") than the graph works fine and the values show up for each date, but I need to use the labels from the table.

```
        GraphData graphData;
        GraphDataList graphDataList = new GraphDataList();
        graphDataList.ListOfGraphData = new List<GraphData>();
        String InsertQuery = "Select name, value from graph1";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            Random random = new Random();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(InsertQuery, conn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           // sa.Fill(ds, "graph");
            int index = 0;
            SqlDataReader da = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (da.Read())
            {

                label.Add(da.GetString(0));

                value.Add(da.GetString(1));
            }
            while (index < label.Count)
            {
                graphData = new GraphData();
                graphData.label =         DateTime.Now.AddDays(index).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                //graphData.value = Convert.ToString(random.Next(index, 10000));
               // graphData.label = label[index];
                graphData.value = value[index];
                graphDataList.ListOfGraphData.Add(graphData);
                index++;

            } 
                    conn.Close();
```

Comment: So what does `label[index]` return for each iteration of the loop? sounds like it returns the same value repeatedly.  Also have a loock at using a `foreach` loop instead of a `while`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the javascript looks like this:

```
        Morris.Line({
            element: 'area-example',
            data: Graph(),
            xkey: 'label',
            ykeys: ['value'],
            labels: ['value']
        });

  function Graph() {
        var data = "";

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:60539/GraphHandler.ashx",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'GraphName': 'line' },
            success: function (result) {
                data = result;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

        return data;
    }
```

In aspx file add: `<div id="area-example"></div>`

`element` parameter is the ID name of `div` tag
`data`: function that return JSON value
`xkey` and `ykey` the name of JSON value, in you example is `"label"` and `"value"`.